# How to run spark job sequentially?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case where in there is a table with one column which has sequence of SQL queries.

I want to run these SQL queries in spark program one after the other and not in parallel. This is because SQL query on Nth row will have dependency on (N-1)th row.

Now due to this constraint I want to execute this sequentially one after the other rather than in parallel. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what's preventing you from executing SQL code in your app: df1 = sqlContext.sql('# query here'), df2 = sqlContext.sql('# query here'). If it should be a separate spark apps you can use bash or python subprocess so you can control exit code. The other option is scheduling tool like Airflow

Comment: It's about Actions. They tend to be sequential unless specific protocols are followed.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit? @thebluephantom

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use something like this:

```
val listOfQueryRows = spark.sqlContext.table("foo_db.table_of_queries")
  .select(col("sql_query"))
  .orderBy(col("query_index"))
  .collectAsList()

listOfQueryRows.forEach(queryRow => spark.sql(queryRow.getString(0)))
```

This will select all your queries in the `sql_query` column, order them by the index given in the `query_index` and collects them in the list `listOfQueryRows` in the driver. The list is then iterated over sequentially executing the query for each returned row.